# Stop propagation on live elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with stopping event propagation. Imagine this scenario:

```
<table id="test">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="row"> </td>
            <td class="row"> </td>
            <td class="row"> </td>
            <td class="row"> </td>
            <td class="row"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="row"> </td>
            <td class="row"> </td>
            <td class="row"> </td>
            <td class="row"> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

And then this code:

```
(function(){
    $('td.row').on('click', function(e){
        if (! e.isPropagationStopped())
             alert('Row clicked!');        
    });
    $('table#test').on('click', 'img.live', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('Image clicked!');            
    });
    $('td.row').html('<img src="http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/161/f/c/nyan_cat_avatar_by_oxoxnaminemayxoxo-d3il6gm.gif" class="live">');
})();​
```

Whenever a image is clicked both events are fired. I want that just fires the event *on* the clicked element. I know that since they are live they are fired once propagation has ended but, is there any workaround?

As far as I've investigated, both events are practically the same but `srcElement` changes from `HTMLTableCellElement` to `HTMLImageElement`. Is this cross-browser consistent?

I've put a demo in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FrsFT/1/) in case you want to watch in action.

Comment: I believe the mechanics of jQuery's delegation system is that the function is bound to `#test`, and when clicked, jQuery checks whether the target element is `img.live`. So the `stopPropagation` is always called *after* `isPropagationStopped`. (I could be wrong, though.)

Comment: That's what I thought too. No workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FrsFT/3/)

The problem is the event has to climb to the parent to find a handler for `<img>`. So it has to pass through `<td>` and fires its handler immediately since it's not a delegated handler.

```
*click*   ,-----------------> (1) fire direct td handler
  img -> td -> tr -> table  
                       '----> (2) fire delegated img handler
                       X<---- (3) e.stopPropagation() //too late!
```

One way to prevent the double event is also add `<td>`'s handler to the table as well. jQuery will then evaluate the two handlers, start with the deepest event and if any of those handlers has `e.stopPropagation()`, events higher up will not fire.

```
$('table#test').on('click', 'img.live', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('Image clicked!');            
});

$('table#test').on('click','td.row', function(e){
     alert('Row clicked!');        
});

*click*                
  img -> td -> tr -> table
                       '----> (1) fire delegated img handler
                       X<---- (2) e.stopPropagation()
                       '----> (3) fire delegated td handler //never gets fired
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but can't you use [event delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/) here?

```
(function(){
    $('#test').on('click', function(e){
        if ( !/img$/i.test((e.target || e.eventSrc).nodeName)){
          alert('row clicked');
        } else {
          alert('image clicked');
        }           

    });
    $('td.row').html('<img src="'+
                     'http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/'+
                     '161/f/c/nyan_cat_avatar_by_'+
                     'oxoxnaminemayxoxo-d3il6gm.gif" class="live">');
})();​
```

It saves you the hassle with propagation. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hzpLn/)